# How to make neural network training charts have a logarithmic vertical axis?

Tags: matlab, plot, neural-network, customization, matlab-figure

When using MATLAB's NN training tool ([`trainNetwork`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/trainnetwork.html)), we get charts that have a linear vertical axis, as shown below:

[image: Current situation]

This chart should provide some graphical feedback regarding the training progress, and it *perhaps does* for classification problems (where the y-axis represents "**Accuracy (%)**"), but in regression problems, the RMSE values might have vastly different orders of magnitude as training progresses - making everything after the initial drop indistinguishable and quite useless.

What I'd like to do is to convert the vertical axis to logarithmic, yielding the following result:

[image: Desired situation]

(I don't mind that some graphical elements move around or get lost in the process, as the curve is what's important to me.)

The way I'm doing it now is by pausing the training process, and manually running

```
set(findall(findall(0,'type','figure'),'type','Axes',...
  'Tag','NNET_CNN_TRAININGPLOT_AXESVIEW_AXES_REGRESSION_RMSE'),'YScale','log');
```

(or some variation thereof, depending on the open figures etc.).

I'm looking for a way to change the scale without user intervention, and do so as close as possible to the start of the training. Also, it would be great if I could choose which chart to rescale (RMSE and/or Loss).

I'm using R2018a.

---

Minimal code required to generate such a figure (based on the MATLAB docs titled "[Train Network for Image Regression](https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/trainnetwork.html#mw_a6eaa015-a2c1-4432-8b91-040f85f64071)"):

```
[XTrain,~,YTrain] = digitTrain4DArrayData;

layers = [ ...
    imageInputLayer([28 28 1])
    convolution2dLayer(12,25)
    reluLayer
    fullyConnectedLayer(1)
    regressionLayer];

options = trainingOptions('sgdm', ...
    'InitialLearnRate',0.001, ...
    'Verbose',false, ...
    'MaxEpochs',5, ...
    'Plots','training-progress');

net = trainNetwork(XTrain,YTrain,layers,options);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can piggyback on the custom [`'OutputFcn'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/trainingoptions.html#bu59f0q-OutputFcn) mechanism available in the training options, and specify there a function which does the rescaling. User control over which axes get rescaled is exerted via the variable `whichAx`.

#### Full code:

```matlab
function net = q51762507()
[XTrain,~,YTrain] = digitTrain4DArrayData;

layers = [ ...
    imageInputLayer([28 28 1])
    convolution2dLayer(12,25)
    reluLayer
    fullyConnectedLayer(1)
    regressionLayer];

whichAx = [false, true]; % [bottom, top]

options = trainingOptions('sgdm', ...
    'InitialLearnRate',0.001, ...
    'Verbose',false, ...
    'MaxEpochs',5, ...
    'Plots','training-progress',...
    'OutputFcn', @(x)makeLogVertAx(x,whichAx) );

net = trainNetwork(XTrain,YTrain,layers,options);

function stop = makeLogVertAx(state, whichAx)
stop = false; % The function has to return a value.
% Only do this once, following the 1st iteration
if state.Iteration == 1
  % Get handles to "Training Progress" figures:
  hF  = findall(0,'type','figure','Tag','NNET_CNN_TRAININGPLOT_FIGURE');
  % Assume the latest figure (first result) is the one we want, and get its axes:
  hAx = findall(hF(1),'type','Axes');
  % Remove all irrelevant entries (identified by having an empty "Tag", R2018a)
  hAx = hAx(~cellfun(@isempty,{hAx.Tag}));
  set(hAx(whichAx),'YScale','log');
end
```

Comment: Hi how would you find the handle for the loss function plot to do the same?

Comment: @Typo - "_User control over which axes get rescaled is exerted via the variable `whichAx`._". In other words, set this variable to e.g. `[true, true]`.

Comment: That I understood, I’m talking about the plot beneath RMSE, whichAx is setting the scale of the RMSE axis, there’s another plot for the loss function. Your code finds the figure for the RMSE plot with the tag attribute on the findall function, which is not the same handle for the loss function plot.

Comment: @Typo Did you try changing `whichAx` to what I said in the previous comment and then running the code? Note that this code finds **all** axes in the figure, so getting it to target the right one is trivial (using the debugger). If the proposed solution doesn't work for you, or you're unsure how to adapt it to your needs, I suggest you post a new question, and link to this Q&A for context.

Comment: Yes, it causes an exception: Expected one output from a curly brace or dot indexing expression, but there were 2 results.

    Error in netScripts>makeLogVertAx (line 79)
          hAx(whichAx).YScale = 'log';

Comment: @Typo I've modified the code to handle setting both charts' Y-axes at the same time if needed (previously you could only do it one at a time, so my 1st comment was incorrect before this edit).